# Ganache cli transaction hash collision

Tags: testrpc, ganache

I am making couple of forwarding transactions (i.e. to contract address that just receives funds and proxifying it to main contract) locally on Ganache CLI running (old `testrpc` does the same result) and found that some transactions from different senders has the **same transaction hash** like below:

```
  // THIS ONE
  Transaction: 0xe0dcb204328627a50b71a05e9c0d258f241ab33ba6cc9d6929b6a4c89c1b70ba
  Gas usage: 207209
  Block Number: 29
  Block Time: Mon May 21 2018 19:16:58 GMT+0700 (+07)

  Transaction: 0x12e8188b4bbd678266e7b92e4c67115bea7452f48f03d30c533caadb3412e2f8
  Gas usage: 177259
  Block Number: 30
  Block Time: Mon May 21 2018 19:17:05 GMT+0700 (+07)

  Transaction: 0x982d265e8199f646493a72c5f08918accc8e90f2e10f4aa1a9b08a67ad0ad5ad
  Gas usage: 162259
  Block Number: 31
  Block Time: Mon May 21 2018 19:17:16 GMT+0700 (+07)

  // AND THIS ONE
  Transaction: 0xe0dcb204328627a50b71a05e9c0d258f241ab33ba6cc9d6929b6a4c89c1b70ba
  Gas usage: 162259
  Block Number: 32
  Block Time: Mon May 21 2018 19:17:26 GMT+0700 (+07)
```

How it could be?

Transactions are created using `ethereumjs-tx` and `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction` with raw data.

Comment: I was bitten by this a couple of week ago. It seems ganache doesn't use the signature just the transaction data to generate tx hash, ie if two different addresses send the transaction with the same nonce, value, to and data they will get the same tx hash. I don't know if this is a feature or bug. Perhaps you can report it in their github repo.

Comment: @Ismael yes, you're right. More over, it is affected somehow by recipient address and amount, but not with sender address. I just changed amount and same TX hash was gone.